# How to swap icon/images of Material design navigation drawer on selection?

Tags: android, navigation, material-design, navigation-drawer

Means default all icon are in red color and on selection it should become black.I am able to change the text color on selection?

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/click_nav_item_change_color"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_course_screen_drawer"
            tools:overide="true" />
```

Comment: try this ref: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Please, provide part of your code where you handle selection changes (in your case changes text color)? Thank you.